# Using DynamicControl with datasource in an external database

Tags: xpages, dynamic-content

I have a problem with loading documents with this code.

```
var c = getComponent("dynp")
c.show("contact",{action:'editDocument',documentId:unid})
```

Or actually it's just an annoying problem.

My `var unid` points to a document in another database but `c.show` expect the document to be in the same database as the DynamicContent code.
I therefore gets an error every time call the `c.show("contact",{action:'editDocument',documentId:unid})`

> **The error**
>
> dynp error mydynamic.xsp Exception occurred calling method  NotesDatabase.getDocumentByUNID(java.lang.String)

The customcontrols data-source is

`<xp:dominoDocument formName="myForm" var="doc1" databaseName="#{javascript:getExternaldb()}" />`

and the document therefore loads correct.
But I still gets the annoying error (Admin is not happy)

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the database name as a parameter. Without ignoreRequestParams, I'm pretty sure this will assume the current database, overwriting whatever you put in the datasource.

Does it work if you pass it in the parameters?

Comment: I tried with the `ignoreRequestParams="true/false"` and the document loads fine. 
The error is happening before it opens the customcontrol. 
I think the d.show command uses the getDocumentByUNID, before it knows of the datasource.

But if I can pass the database name as parameter in the `d.show`, that would be fine. But I don't now the syntax?

Comment: The syntax of other parameters seems consistent with property names, so I would guess `databaseName="#{javascript:getExternaldb()}"` would work (you can still use SSJS within CSJS, it just gets evaluated prior to the the CSJS being passed to the browser.

Comment: I found the correct syntax
 

`var db:NotesDatabase = getExternalDb();
var dbserver = db.getServer()
var dbfilepath = @ReplaceSubstring(db.getFilePath(),"\\","/");
var dbname = dbserver+"!!"+dbfilepath;
var unid =viewentries.getDocument().getUniversalID();
var d = getComponent("dynC");

d.show("contact",action:'editDocument',databaseName:dbname,documentId:unid})};`

Comment: But actually it was not the `d.show` that gave the error. I had some code that checked if the documentId from url-parameters did exist in the current database. And this gave the `NotesDatabase.getDocumentByUNID(java.lang.String)` error. 

Thanks for the input which helped me find the solution.

Comment: With OpenNTF Domino API, NotesDatabase.getApiPath() is available, which returns the server!!filepath format

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do what you're doing.  I don't get what you're trying to do really. I never even saw the action part of c.show.  And only rarely do i ever use getComponent.

You have a dynamic panel and a working custom control right?  You're trying to control edit mode vs read mode right?  Why don't you just set a viewScoped variable with something like editMode=true / false.  And then have the custom control read that in to determine the mode.  No need that that action business...

Comment: Parameters used in c.show are found in documentation detailing how to open a document in a dynamic content control from a view panel. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/extlib_controls_dynamic.html

Comment: The c.show("contact",{action:'editDocument',documentId:unid}) transform to an url /myDb.nsf#content=contact&action=editDocument&documentId=002767D4D4DABC5BC1257FE‌​A00420593 and this works fine.
It's not an issue with editDocument/OpenDocument. It's "just" the annoying problem that the d.show gives the error in the log.nsf, when the document is stored in another database. 
I can off course just compute the URL myself, which I believe also would work fine, but when the show function is available, why not use it?

Comment: Why not use it? For the very reason you're having a problem.  The built in stuff is not always the easiest to work with. :)